# Cannot fetch value to display item

Tags: reactjs, react-props

i was trying to fetch the value of the functions(increment, decrement,remove) and the value of the item(id, price...) to display in the cartItem but it isn't working, is there anything wrong with my params? please help me to fix it! Thank you so much!

CartList.js:

```
import React from "react";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";

export default function CartList(props) {
  const { items } = props;
  console.log(props, "inside cart");
  return (
    <div>
      {items.cart.map((item) => (
        <CartItem key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

CartItem.js:

```
import React from "react";

function CartItem(props) {
  
  const { id, title, img, price, total, count } = props.item;
  const { increment, decrement, removeItem } = props.value;

  return (
    <div className="row my-1 text-capitalize text-center">
      <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
        <img
          src={img}
          style={{ width: "5rem", heigth: "5rem" }}
          className="img-fluid"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2 ">
        <span className="d-lg-none">product :</span> {title}
      </div>
      <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2 ">
        <strong>
          <span className="d-lg-none">price :</span> ${price}
        </strong>
      </div>
      <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2 my-2 my-lg-0 ">
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div>
            <span className="btn btn-black mx-1">-</span>
            <span className="btn btn-black mx-1">{count}</span>
            <span className="btn btn-black mx-1">+</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2 ">
        <div className=" cart-icon" onClick={() => removeItem(id)}>
          <i className="fas fa-trash" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2 ">
        <strong>item total : ${total} </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CartItem;
```

Sandbox link for better observation:https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-code-addict-forked-rrkuz?file=/src/cart/CartItem.js

Comment: You did not passed 'props.value' into CartItem

Comment: it doesn't work either as i pass "props.value"

Comment: You are offending him You have not passed the prop correctly and that's the problem @MinseoLee had found that out and helped you so you can pass the props and can update him about the status with the error message you got if there is an error.

Comment: @naha props.value should include increment, decrement, removeItem. Is props.value includes those methods?

Comment: Please check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-code-addict-forked-rrkuz?file=/src/cart/CartItem.js